# Debug not working in Monodroid 4.2.3

Tags: xamarin.android

Since My co-worker and I have downloaded and installed Monodroid 4.2.3, we have been unable to run debug and have the breakpoints work. What do we need to do to make them work?

Answer (score 0):

Users on the mailing list have been [discussing the same problem](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/4-2-3-debugger-td5710420.html) in 4.2.3.

A better place to report this would be in their [bug tracker](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/describecomponents.cgi?product=Mono%20for%20Android). In the meantime you could downgrade back to 4.2.2 if this is causing you a lot of trouble.